# Release COM Object in C#

Tags: c#, com, outlook

I know this has been discussed earlier but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I have an e-mail file (.msg) which I open like below and then call Display.

```
oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(fileName);
mail.Display(false);
oApp = null; // do I need to release this object ?
```

users can close it and re-open it. Before they click "reopen" I check to see if the window still exists, if yes .. then just send a SetForeground(hwnd) to that window. if Not, that means user closed it so just release the mailItem object and open again.

```
 public static void ReleaseCOMObject(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item) {
        int r = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
        while (r != 0) {
            r = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
        }
    }
```

If I try to open the same file again. It "sometimes" throws a "file in use exception" So, I think even though I am releasing the MailItem .. its not been released properly.

What can I do to ensure that its released properly. closing and reopening a file is a very common scenario.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: You should only "release" when you increment the reference counter, "release"ing other peoples references can cause problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using .NET's COM-interop features (you are) then you shouldn't need to worry about this.

COM tracks reference counts - and when the ref count reaches 0 COM objects get released automatically - and .NET takes care of working with the standard COM reference counting mechanism for you.

If you were P/Invoking into a C library things might be different - but you shouldn't have any worries in a standard scenario like yours.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong. I noticed that once I get "File In use Exception" restarting my outlook do the trick. What kind of clean up do I need for "oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();" ?

Comment: Its working now -> There was another module which was holding on to the MailItem and was not releasing it.

Comment: BTW, just wanted to let you know that I still had to "ReleaseCOMObject" to make it working.

Comment: @karephul - I don't disagree with Nanhydrin that "dispose early, dispose often" is always a good idea, regardless of the situation. If something is IDisposable it should be wrapped in a `using` statement or used within a disposable class and disposed when the main class is disposed. However, baring special circumstances, you shouldn't HAVE to call ReleaseCOMObject manually. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Doing things like this:

```
mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(fileName);
```

will cause the references to not be disposed of even when you call ReleaseComObject because the reference to the child object hasn't been disposed of properly.

You should make the calls like this:

```
session = oApp.Session;
mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)session.OpenSharedItem(fileName);
```

And you should dispose of each of these sub-objects, like session, in turn.

Comment: I noticed that if outlook is not running on my machine .. closing and reopening (the way I described earlier) works fine. I think some how outlook is holding the reference to that file. Any pointers there ? I tried releasing the Session object separately as well (din't work)

Comment: Are you calling the Marshal.ReleaseComObject method in the same method where you're getting the mail item or are you doing it in some onclose event handler or something like that?

Comment: Before user can open a mail item, we check to see if there is a window with same title. If not, then ReleaseComObject(mailItem) .. and open again. [User could have closed the email window] .. Basically I hold on the MailItem as long as I can so that I can save it periodically.

Comment: BTW, can I ReleaseComObject(item) in different thread ? like in background ? I noticed that even when "ReleaseComObject" is able to release the objects it takes a lot of time (** there is only one reference)

Comment: You cannot depend on the garbage collector to pick things up immediately after you've disposed of them so it's generally best to dispose of things as soon as you're done with them. I expect you could release the COM object anywhere but personally, I prefer to release COM objects in the same method where I use them, or if the scope is outside the current method then to release them as soon as is appropriate, this reduces the likelihood that I will miss an object and end up with something hanging open.