# Releasing COM objects in a background thread

Tags: c#, com, outlook

Extension to [Release COM Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263481/release-com-object-in-c-sharp)

I noticed that saving the MailItem and releasing is a time consuming task. So, it is safe to do the following ? (pseudo-code below)

```
Thread 1 (main thread)
- Open 10 (different .msg files) - MailItems [List<MailItem> items]
- user works on them and want to save and close all of them with one click.

- On_save_All_click (runs on main thread)
- Do
- toBeClearedList.addAll(items);
- items.clear() [so that main thread cannot access those items]
- BG_Thread.ExecuteAsyn(toBeClearedList);
- End

Thread 2 (background thread) (input - List<MailItems>) 
- foreach(MailItem item in input)
    item.save();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)
- done
```

I wrote couple of tests and looks like its working; Just want to know if its safe to do so ? "Releasing COM objects in different thread than the one in which it was created"

Thanks

Karephul

Answer (score 6):

When using COM from unmanaged code (C/C++), the rules are pretty strict: you can only call methods on an interface from the same apartment that you acquired the object on. So if you obtain an interface pointer on an STA thread, then only that thread is allowed to call any of the methods. If you obtain an interface pointer on an MTA thread, then only other threads in the same MTA can use that pointer. Any other use that crosses apartments requires that the interface pointer is marshaled to the other apartment.

However, that's unamanged world. .Net adds a whole layer on top of COM which buries a lot of these low-level details, and for the most part, once you get your hands on an interface, you can pass that interface around between threads as much as you please without having to worry about the old threading rules. What's happening here is that it are actually passing around references to an object called a "Runtime Callable Wrapper" (RCW), and it is managing the underlying COM interface, and controlling access to it accordingly. (It takes on the burden of upholding the COM apartment rules so that you don't have to, and that's why it can appear that the old COM threading rules don't apply in .Net: they do, they're just hidden from you.)

So you can safely call Release or other methods from another thread: but be aware that if the original thread was STA, then calling those methods will cause the underlying RCW to marshal the call back to the original owning thread so that it still upholds the underling COM rules. So using a separate thread may not actually get you any performance in the end!

Some articles worth reading that fill in some of the details here:

- [The mapping between interface pointers and runtime callable wrappers (RCWs)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mbend/archive/2007/04/18/the-mapping-between-interface-pointers-and-runtime-callable-wrappers-rcws.aspx) - good overview of some of the details of how RCW's work, but it doesn't say much about threading.
- [Improving Interop Performance - Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx#scalenetchapt07_topic9) - some good notes on when to use or not use ReleaseComObject, and how it works with the RCWs.
- [cbrumme's WebLog - Apartments and Pumping in the CLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/02/66219.aspx) - more internals than you're likely to want to know; this is a couple of CLR releases out of date, but still gives a good insight into how .Net covers over many of the underlying COM issues.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember my COM properly (I always hated that technology, way too complicated), if the COM object is single-threaded (that is, belongs in a single-threaded-apartment), releasing it from another thread isn't going to do you any good - it's just going to execute the actual release code in your main thread.

You *are* going to see a little difference between your code, and releasing the objects from the main thread in one loop. If you release the objects in one loop, your UI is going to be unresponsive until you release all messages. By using a secondary thread, your UI thread will release one message, then handle other events, then release another, and so on. You can get the same effect by sending yourself a message (or using a Dispatcher if you have a WPF application), and avoid having another thread.

Comment: as you said the only thing I want to achieve is "response UI". As long as its safe to start another thread and release those COM objects safely (without any unwanted exceptions) I am good. (I will keep testing)