# Save Overwrite and changes using Excel.Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, save

All,

I have the below code which works okay, however I would like to save (Overwrite changes) instead of SaveAs. To my knowledge the Close(True) Should achieve this however it still provides the user with a save as option. :S

Any help / recommendations on the below would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Dynamic.Script_8D58F1E2C23B36A
{
    // Script generated by Pega Robotics Studio 8.0.1072.0
    // Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
    [OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
    [OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D58F1E2C23B36A")]
    public sealed class Script
    {
        public void deleterow(string WorkbookName2)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet myWorkSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
            myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            myWorkBook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(WorkbookName2, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            myWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)myWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)myWorkSheet.Application.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
            range.Select();
            range.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
            myWorkBook.Close(true);
            myApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this to stop DisplayAlerts from appearing:

```
myApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

And then if you want to save with specifying a file name, you can do this:

```
//specifying a file name
myWorkSheet.SaveAs(filename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
myWorkBook.Close(true);
```

Or you can do it short hand by doing the following:

```
myWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=YourFileDirectory/FileName)
```

If you just want to save a file that exists without specifying the file directory/file name. Just do this:

```
myApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
myWorkBook.Save();
myWorkBook.Close(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Apologies I may not have been clear in my original post, I would like to save over the original file. So the aim is to not saveas just to save will re-edit my original post.

Comment: I've updated my comment for you. This should explain what you could do and the different options :)

Answer (score 0):

You can "silence" Excel temporarily

```
myApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
myWorkBook.Close(true);
myApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Well and you should think about releasing your COM objects

Example:

```
if (obj != null && Marshal.IsComObject(obj))
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Would releasing the object remove the Excel from the task manager?

Comment: ```myApp.Quit();``` Closes the excel app and after that it shouldn't be visible in the taskmanager any more, if nothing goes wrong.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263481/release-com-object-in-c-sharp for more information about releasing COM Objects